# Reset a single USB port

Tags: usb, port, reset

I have some USB devices, that sometimes need to be physically removed and plugged back in. They are mostly USB mobile broadband devices. For some cases I only have to unplug the device and put it back in to the USB port. In some cases I have to first remove the device, then plug in some other USB device and then the first one again to make it work properly.

Those mobile devices create a virtual COM port for internet. It sounds a little weird.

Is there any way I could do this more easily? Something like few commands in a .bat file? Or is it just the USB standard that limits users' possibilities? I can't reset all my USB ports, because in my case it's easier to physically reset those devices.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a way to do this by software, although you could try disabling and enabling the USB controller in Device Manager. This depends on the computer's APM though and may not work. You also can't control it for certain ports - all ports on the controller will be shut off (careful if you have a USB mouse). **Also, if your USB ports are having problems consistently, it's time to change the hardware.**

Comment: A similar question has recently been asked on Software Recommendations and seems to have a good answer: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/program-to-reset-usb-ports

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell

Be careful, if your Keyboard is connected to the motherboard like this, you won't be able to type again either, unless you have it run as a BAT script, which would be OK, 'cos it will restart the service again:

```
ps Set-ItemProperty  "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR" -name start -Value 4
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1
ps Set-ItemProperty  "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR" -name start -Value 3
```

Run that as Admin.

The top line, disables all the USB ports, then it will sit there for 5 seconds on line #2, and then re-enable all the USB ports again for you. It disables their drivers.

I suggest adding `@ECHO OFF` to the top of the BAT file, and saving it as `.BAT`

---

#### EDIT:

I just realised you only wanted to disable 1 USB port. This will do all of them. If you know much about PowerShell, you can find a way to target just a single USB port.